# UICollectionView loses the last item focus when scroll

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, collectionview

I have a horizontal `UICollectionView` with a few items. When I select one of them, I obtain some data from the API and I display it in the screen.

When I start scrolling the `UICollectionView` to select another category, the focus go to the first option and not remain in the last item I selected.

I'm not sure if it's a bug from my code or I need to implement some function to solve it.

I have this code related with the declaration of the `UICollectionView`:

I'm implemented this protocols: `UICollectionViewDataSource`, `UICollectionViewDelegate`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // get a reference to our storyboard cell
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //call to the presenter to call API
}
```

Also, I needed a observer to select the first item when the screen is loaded:

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    if let observedObject = object as? UICollectionView, observedObject == collectionView {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.collectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.bottom)
            self.collectionView(self.collectionView, didSelectItemAt: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0))
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Put relevant code here

Comment: Have you tried putting a print(#function) statement in your observer function to show when it is getting called? I suspect it is being called all the time whenever anything changes in the collection view. I am not sure why you need to use this structure to select the first cell on load - the first cell will load by default.

Comment: Yes, I found that the observer is called every time I scroll the collection view. I'm going to change the way to select the default value